# simple html dom find gives error Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, html, simple-html-dom

i am using simple_html_dom to get a text from a website but it gives me

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\wamp64\www\fetch.php on line 6
```

the website has this.

```
<div>
 <div class="info">number: (IUL)306/306/2016/68</div>
 <div class="info">published date: 14 june 2016</div>
 <div class="info">published time: 1442</div>
 <div class="info">expiry time 23 june 2016 1100</div>
<div>
```

my php looks like this which i am trying to get the second div with class info.

```
<php?include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('http://www.example.com');
$html->save();

foreach($html->find('div[class=info]', 2) as $e)
        $pdate = $e->innertext . '<br>';

 echo "pdate: $pdate";
 ?>
```

any  possible solutions to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're providing the index:

```
$html->find('div[class=info]', 2)
                               ^ this one
```

You're going to get the element directly. So you might as well use the `->innertext` straight ahead. You already got the third element:

```
$info = $html->find('div[class=info]', 2);
echo $info->innertext;
```

No need for that `foreach`.

If you need that `foreach`, then just use this alone:

```
$html->find('div[class=info]')
                      // ^ note: the second argument is omitted
```

This will give you the collection of elements found. Example:

```
foreach($html->find('div[class=info]') as $e) {
    echo $e->innertext, '<br/>';
}
```

This is actually covered in the [manual](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm).

Its under ***How to find HTML elements?*** section.

Comment: Thanks that worked. do you know why the error occurred though?

Comment: @MohamedAthif its already on the single element, thus the error, sure glad this helped

Answer (score 1):

You can get your result simply by doing this:

```
<?php
require_once('simple_html_dom.php');

$html = file_get_html('http://www.example.com');
$html->save();

$pdate  = $html->find('div[class=info]', 1)->plaintext;

echo "pdate: $pdate";
```